# Rationale for explicit conversion operator on functor

Tags: c++, stl, static-analysis

While I was on a short break, my workplace switched to using a static code analyzer.
They ran it over the project I am working on and one particular problem flagged by the analyzer goes like this (simplified example):

```cpp
struct calcSomething
{
    int result;

    calcSomething() : result(0) {}

    void operator()(const int v) { /*does something*/ }
    operator int() const { return result; }
};

void foo()
{
    std::vector<int> myvector(10);
    // exercise for reader: stick some values in `myvector`

    int result = std::for_each(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), calcSomething());
}
```

The analyzer flags the following issues:

```
warning: CodeChecker: 'operator int' must be marked explicit to avoid unintentional implicit conversions [google-explicit-constructor]
    operator int() const { return result; }
```

The suggested fix to the functor reads:

```cpp
struct calcSomething
{
    ... 
    explicit operator int() const { return result; }
};
```

But if I fix my functor as suggested, the static analyzer quickly flags the following issue:

```
warning: CodeChecker: no viable conversion from '(anonymous namespace)::calcSomething' to 'int' [clang-diagnostic-error]
```

I now need to add the explicit cast:

```cpp
void foo()
{
    ...
    int total = static_cast<int>(std::for_each(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), calcSomething()));
}
```

The above example is a mere simplification of the real problem which would otherwise just add filler and no substance.

I have seen plenty of examples of functors like the one I describe here in text books and programming reference web pages.
I have never considered these unsafe. I have never seen anyone flag these as unsafe.

So does the code analyzer have a point?
Or is it a little overzealous to make my functor's conversion operator explicit and as a result make me add the static cast?

Purely from an aesthetic point, I feel that a simple problem with an elegant solution now accrues a lot of ugly syntactic padding.
But perhaps that is the price we pay for writing safe(r) code.

> side note: TIL that `explicit` applies not only to ctors

**Edit**

It seems some people are unable to read beyond the example code I provided  (pretty textbook stuff) and still suggest other algorithms/idioms, completely failing to see that the actual question is about conversion operators on functors whose sole purpose is to calculate and return an algorithm's result.

If the question was about how to improve on an adding algorithm, then the title would have said so.

So I decided to hide any implementation details in this edit to make it easier for these people.

Sorry that some of the comments below now no longer make any sense, but the record got stuck so I had to move the needle a bit in order to move things forward (hopefully).

Comment: This is obviously a very subjective question, so I'm not entirely sure what kind of answer you expect? Static code checkers are basically just mere if-then-elses and rather dumb. If you disagree with a suggestion then ignore it? In this particular case, I wholeheartedly agree with you, and believe that implicit conversion in such a specific and isolated usecase does no harm. Despite this, in more general cases, implicit conversion can be very dangerous obviously.

Comment: On a site note: There is `std::accumulate` and `std::reduce`

Comment: If this question is subjective then I would expect it to get closed soon.
But is it really subjective, though?
Re other methods; I know, but felt I had to make a concise example and arrived at this.

Comment: `#include <numeric>` and just use `std::accumulate` instead this strange class of yours.

Comment: @Marek R "Please don't get hung up about c++ standards or on how this code can be rewritten if I just do X, Y or use idiom Z" - it's in the question. I suggest you read it?

Comment: @iwarv well, its opinion-based (as in, asking for a matter of taste), and honestly it is not even entirely clear to me what the actual question even is. If the question is: "why are implicit conversions potentially dangerous?" then the answer is: Imagine a `std::string_view` with implicit conversion to `const char*` (which seems useful at first) in conjunction with functions expecting c-style strings.

Comment: You are doing something stage not something unsafe. Code in this form does something what is unexpected and hard to read. If you use `std::accumulate` code intention is clear for the reader on other hand this `int total = std::for_each(` is causing reader to raise eyebrows (you can't understand what it does without reading `for_each` documentation and your functor class). Note that code is not written for compiler, but for future readers: you or your coworker. This is also the reason code analyzer is picking on you.

Comment: Okay, SO want me to simplify the problem, yet when I do people take the example at face value and cannot get past it.
How about you (@Marek R) imagining ANY functor doing something entirely different from adding stuff together? Will that help?

Comment: operator const int() const { return result; } would this satisfy the static analizer?

Comment: Again assignment form `std::for_each(` is a WAT with conversion or without it. I would reject such code on review (doesn't meter if it works). If you have to jump to other sources to understand code this means code is badly written, without care. Code analyzer works great with code which is written using common patterns. If your pattern is quirky code analyzer is confused too.

Comment: How can static analyzer know that you want actually **implicit** conversion?

Comment: https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#c164-avoid-implicit-conversion-operators

Comment: For me the answer very simple, code is specifically written to rely on implicit conversion, so code analyzer is incorrect and should be silenced (usually there methods to do so).

Comment: @Alessandro Teruzzi `type qualifiers ignored on function return type`.
I could have guessed that, and I feel cheap for falling for this ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do away with any conversion operators altogether. What's wrong with:

```
int result = std::for_each(...).get();
```

where `get()` does the same as your current `operator int`.

You know that the result of for_each is not an integer, it's  your function object. Why, why would you want to avoid making the conversion from a function to a value explicit? It is, by all means, a questionable idea. Sure, you can still do it, but you want clean warning-free code right? Well, clean, warning free code, in my book, should not auto-convert functions to integers. I agree `static_cast` is almost equally ugly, that's why I am suggesting a named function

Comment: I'll be honest, I was waiting for this answer. We (collectively / at work) came up with the same compromise this morning. I think these textbook examples in books and on the internet should teach the same. It's good to have this documented on SO, though.

Comment: Be advised anyone, that `for_each` returns *a copy* of your functor. So if your functor returns "something bigger" than -say- an int then please don't be fooled into thinking that this "get" function on your functor could return by const reference. Bad things may happen if you do.